# SplitView Application with Custom TableView in DetailView

Tags: ipad

Dear members,
We are relativly new to IPAD development.
We are working on a splitview application (using standard project template) where in the rootview controller we use a CustomTableViewCell that is populated from a propertylist (UIImageView and UILabel) this works perfect. When clicked the detailview shows the passed selection.
so far nothing new.
In the DetailView however we need to show a UITableView with a SecondCustomTableViewcell that is populted from a) a different propertylist for fixed data and one of the UILabels needs to be updated via the passed selection from the rootcontroller.
imagine this
Rootview controller shows a list of countries with a flag.
DetailView should show a list of countries (different datasource) and one of the UILabels is updated with the selection
e.g. click on France on the left shows the tableview with all countries where UILabel selectedcountry shows France.
I've been googling for 4 days and reading a lot of post but didnt find the right one yet.

Any help with sample is appreciated

Peter

Nobody?

Answer (score 0):

You can keep references, like IBOutlets in rootViewController (TableViewController/Left panel)  of splitview, of the detailviewcontroller (UIViewController etc). When an item is selected from the table, update what you need to update in that detailViewController and redraw it.

Eg:
Create another table inside right panel:detailViewController and label if you need. Make detailViewController the datasource for that table. When an item is selected in left panel, update data and label and redraw detailView.

hope this helps.

1.

```
   //In detailView,
     @interface detailViewController: UIViewController <UITableViewDatasource>{
           //blabla
           //This table has been added through XIB,
           UITableView *secondTable;
     }

     @property(retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView * secondTable;

     @end
```

1. Update detailViewController's data whenever a cell is selected (by passing a message to it) in rootViewcontroller, then call reloadData on this table in that method.
2. change label in the same method.